What is the meaning of "Mitsuki. Rhymes with nookie."?
Here's a little bit of context from the movie Scent of a Woman (1992), starring Al Pacino:

Gail: Why don't we all sit down?
Lieutenant Colonel Frank Slade: Ooh. Mitsuki. Rhymes with nookie. Be
careful. When the wife gets restless, the wife gets racy.

What is the meaning of Mitsuki. Rhymes with nookie? There's no character named Mitsuki in the film. Is this some kind of expression that I'm not familiar with? Any help is appreciated.

Consistent with the title of the film, Colonel Slade makes a point of smelling the perfume worn by the women he encounters, and commenting on it.
The scene you're asking about is when the Colonel and Charlie have gone to the house of the Colonel's brother for Thanksgiving.  They are standing just inside the front door, and the greetings are awkward and tense.  The Colonel's conversation is rude and insulting.  Gail is his nephew's wife, and to defuse the tension, she walks up to the Colonel and Charlie and suggests they all sit down.  The Colonel turns his head toward her, inhales and says "Mitsuki."  It's the name of the perfume she's wearing (or rather, Mitsouko). "Nookie" is a slang word referring sexual intercourse - so he's implying her choice  of that perfume indicates she's bored and looking for sex.
There are several other times he identifies women's scents.  Earlier in the same scene, he hugs his brother's wife Gretchen, saying, "Let's have a whiff", but without naming her perfume.  Later in the film he meets a young woman in the restaurant and says, "You know, I detect a fragrance in the air.  Don't tell me what it is.  Ogleby Sisters Soap!" Near the end of the film, a female teacher from Charlie's school speaks with the Colonel.  During the conversation, he inhales and says, "Fleurs de Rocaille."
